# Question about paragraph in The Mathematics of Signal Processing

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I'm working through Damelin and Miller's The Mathematics of Signal Processing for class and there is a paragraph about the Discrete Fourier Transform which simply defeats me:

[image]

How can a Fourier coefficient be 'projected'? And against what basis? I'm really having trouble understanding this and would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: @xXACEXx Is it that rare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the Euclidean algorithm has to do with this, other than also using long integer division/division-with-remainder.

The projection is not of the single coefficient, but of the full sequence $\{\hat f(a)\}_{a\in\Bbb Z}$ to the finite sequence
$$
a\mapsto \sum_{b\in\Bbb Z}\hat f(a+bN), ~~~ a=0,1...,N-1.
$$
To make this a true projection, one would have to extend this finite sequence to a doubly infinite sequence by zero-padding. Then applying the summation-projection again, each sum has only one non-trivial term, so that indeed the square of the operator is the operator itself.

Comment: On what subspace would you be projecting?

Comment: Never mind, I think I get it. Thanks!

Comment: The subspace of finite sequences with support $0,..,N-1$. The language as given is a little suspect, as you can not apply the summation again to the periodic continuation of the finite sequence, so there "projection" is more figurative, in the sense of information reduction.